# Using "at this hour" in the context of early morning rather that late night

Tags: phrase-usage

From what I understand the phrase **"at this hour"** stands for **"at this late time of the night"**, but can it also be used to say **"at this early time in the morning"**?

Comment: Just because people often use (surprised / complaintive) ***at this hour*** in contexts where it's the ***lateness*** of the situation that's surprising doesn't mean it can't be used in other contexts where the time at which something is happening is "unusual" for that event. Feasibly ***at this hour*** might be ***in the middle of the afternoon***, at which time someone is doing something that normally happens either very early OR very late. It's ***context*** that defines why the time and the event are a bad match.

Comment: On the first page or results from a Google Books search for **do that at this hour** I find *"And you will do that at this hour?” “I woke up already three hours ago.”* Which from the start of the paragraph we see is around 11am. Neither ridiculously early OR late, for most people in most contexts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"At this hour" has no specific time of day. It can even mean no specific time. In some contexts, it's just a poetic way of saying "now". There are countless examples in literature of "hour" referring not to a time period or an exact hour on the clock, but just time in general.

CNN has a program titled "At This Hour". It airs at 11 am in the U.S.

"At this hour of our greatest peril..." -- Something a leader might say about the current times.

"I can't believe I haven't had breakfast yet at this hour" (it's 3 pm, so late for not having had breakfast or perhaps any meal).

(It's 10 pm) "At this hour, I used to get ready to go clubbing. But now, all I want to do is go to bed."

"Why are you up already at this hour?" said at 7 am on Saturday, when one can sleep later if not obligated to be up because of work or kids or pets.